# Why does deleting/dropping a column/row in pandas cause assigning values to not work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row, assign

So basically this code:

```
df.iloc[df[(df.Handcap == 2) | (df.Handcap == 3 ) | (df.Handcap == 4)].Handcap.index, 11] = 1
```

Only works, *aka assigns values to some cells that satisfy a certain condition*, if I didn't use the `drop` or `delete` methods before I run this code in pandas, such as:

```
del df['ID']
```

Why does this happen and how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You question is not fully clear, I think a small sample dataset would be helpful

Comment: It turned out to be a key issue, thank you so much for your time

Comment: OK, then maybe delete the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with converting mask by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to numpy array:

```
df.iloc[df.Handcap.isin([2,3,4]).to_numpy(), 11] = 1
```

If need remove rowsmatch or not match by condition in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.Handcap.isin([2,3,4])]
df2 = df[~df.Handcap.isin([2,3,4])]
```

Comment: It still won't assign the values in the original dataframe :( 
What's odd is that it works perfectly fine if I didn't drop rows/cols before it

Comment: @soup - hmmm, what is error?

Comment: @soup - because if some keyerror problem should be `12th` column not exist

Comment: Ohh it really was a key issue, I didn't notice that at all. Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loc` with the reverse approach:

```
mask = (df.Handcap == 2) | (df.Handcap == 3 ) | (df.Handcap == 4)
df.loc[mask, df.columns[11]] = 1
```

Comment: Still the same issue, the values aren't assigned in the original dataframe :(

Comment: @soup I think you need to provide a full example in your question

Answer (score 0):

You need use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), wihtout `.index`. We could also use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
df.loc[df.Handcap.isin([2,3,4]), df.columns[11]] = 1
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it still won't assign the values in the original df.